# Automating NonEnglish website using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Iam trying to automate a website which also has a link to its French site . When I launch this french site , all the product description, currency etc turns to french. 
My question is related to automating this french site with WebDriver.

Currently Iam passing the french words (product name/its description etc) as normal string to my Java Selenium code and it seems to work.

### Test code which seems to work:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-nouveautes"));
String str = el.findElement(By.className("highlight")).getText();

String searchItem = "Tri, table d'appoint, frêne naturel";
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys(searchItem);
driver.findElement(By.className("btns search")).click();
```

Is this the right way to automate a non-english site - passing strings as it is  and retrieving the text in the same way ?  In some links they mention about changing the locale of the browser to specific language. Is that necessary ? 
Tried googling , but couldnt find a good answer.

Iam thinking of using FitNesse for writing the tests

Heres couple of snippets of the html source :

```
 <label for="search" style="display:none;">Recherche :</label>
    <input id="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text" />
    <!--
    <button type="submit" title="Recherche" class="button"><span><span>Recherche</span></span></button>
    -->
    <button class="btns search" type="submit">
    </button>


 <div id="slide_one" class="xxxxxxWorksSlide">
        <p id="slideOne_title">En boutique, un fauteuil de designer <br> se vend en général</p>
        <span class="price-dashed" id="slideOne_left"></span>        
            <p id="slideOne_price">1 500 €</p>        
        <span class="price-dashed" id="slideOne_right"></span>
        <p id="slideOne_copy">Son design a de quoi vous xxx. Mais sa fabrication coûte seulement 250 €. Soit une marge de 500 %.</p>
        <a id="slideOne_btns" class="btns" title="" href="#"><span class="button_label">xxx change les règles<span class="chevron">»</span></span></a>
    </div>
```

Sorry if this is a really silly question. 
Thanks for looking at my post.

Comment: If it is working, what is your question?

Comment: Hi Elliott, Iam quite new to WebDriver and hence wasnt sure whether mine was a good approach. Also these were initial simple tests that I ran. Worried whether i will hit major issues later once i start automating the page based on my initial tests.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right way to automate a non-english site - passing strings as it is and retrieving the text in the same way ?

It's not the wrong way.  Personally I think it's the easiest way, but you need to make sure that you have UTF-8 as the encoding for all the files, otherwise you'll run into issues with other people looking at your files.

> In some links they mention about changing the locale of the browser to specific language. Is that necessary ?

It's only necessary if you are explicitly testing `make sure that the language works when the browsers locale is fr`

You could of course, which i think would be best practice, is to open the base url using the language.  E.g: `http://example.com?lang=fr`

Answer (score 0):

> In some links they mention about changing the locale of the browser
>   to specific language. Is that necessary ?

Setting a locale in the browser will cause it to change the `Accept-Language` header that gets sent with each request.

Whether or not this will make a difference comes down to the site your testing — while most sites won't redirect you away from a particular version if you ask for it specifically, they may be using your locale, gleaned from this header, to present things like currency or dates in different formats.

Some sites go further, e.g. the new [BBC radio player](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/), that's using just the locale to present translated content, rather than having multiple URLs.

In short, the importance comes down to what you're testing (which hopefully you know the functionality of in advance :) )

Comment: - Thanks for the valuable info.

Answer (score 0):

To support your **multiple languages** you can use **[Java Resource Bundle API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)**. This way you just need to add new Resource bundle file for each new language without changing any code.

STEP 1) Send the SITE-LANG as vmArguments to your Test.

```
java -DSITE-LANG=fr
```

STEP 2) Define resource bundle file MyResources_fr.properties in classpath.

```
mySearchItemKey=Tri, table d'appoint, frêne naturel
```

STEP 3) Load the resource bundle during beforeSuite or beforeTest based on System Property.

```
String siteLanguage = System.getProperty("SITE-LANG");
ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResources", new Locale(siteLanguage ));
```

STEP 4) Remove hard coding of text and Access the value from resource bundle.

```
// Your code will become  
String searchItem = myResources.getString("mySearchItemKey");
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys(searchItem);
```